# Displaying the daily increase using data from the database

Tags: php, mysql, window-functions, mysql-8.0

I have a table in which I store the data I get using PHP from the API, the table looks like this:

| ID | count | timestamp |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 6285 | 123 | 21.11 18:54 |
| 6284 | 122 | 21.11 18:53 |
| 6283 | 121 | 21.11 18:52 |
| 6282 | 120 | 21.11 18:51 |

What I want to achieve is something like: **In the last 24 hours, the number has gone up by X**

To retrieve data from DB I use:

```
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
{
// generating HTML table etc
// echo-ign data with $row['timestamp']
}
```

**My thought was to get the first write in 24 hours and the last write and get the difference, but I am not able to transfer this idea to PHP**

Comment: What MySQL version used?

Comment: @SlavaRozhnev using ibmysql - mysqlnd 7.4.3 && phpMyAdmin

Comment: 7.4.3 - is PHP version. For get MySQL version run `SELECT VERSION();` in PHPMyAdmin

Comment: 8.0.27-0ubuntu0.20.04.1

Comment: OK, so you can use window functions. Look my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modern MySQL versions since v.8.0 provides `window functions` such 'FIRST_VALUE':

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    DATE(`timestamp`) as day,
    FIRST_VALUE(`count`) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(`timestamp`) ORDER BY `timestamp`) as start_day_count,
    FIRST_VALUE(`count`) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(`timestamp`) ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC) as end_day_count
FROM t;
```

PHP solution can be next (using PDO module):

```
<?php
$query = "
    SELECT DISTINCT
        FIRST_VALUE(`count`) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(`timestamp`) ORDER BY `timestamp`) as start_day_count,
        FIRST_VALUE(`count`) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(`timestamp`) ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC) as end_day_count
    FROM t WHERE DATE(`timestamp`) = '2021-11-21';";

$stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
$stmt->execute();
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

print_r($row);
```

Here you can [test PHP with MySQL window functions](https://phpize.online/?phpses=e8beab403fead130b6f1455b0b5f00f4&sqlses=e1554bf8b9616b4121dddfe87f9ebe5e&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql80)

or using mysqli:

```
<?php
$query = "
    SELECT DISTINCT
        FIRST_VALUE(`count`) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(`timestamp`) ORDER BY `timestamp`) as start_day_count,
        FIRST_VALUE(`count`) OVER (PARTITION BY DATE(`timestamp`) ORDER BY `timestamp` DESC) as end_day_count
    FROM t WHERE DATE(`timestamp`) = '2021-11-21';";

$result = mysqli_query($mysqli, $query);

$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

print_r($row);
```

[PHP mysqli demo](https://phpize.online/?phpses=6d92a105ed872eb58b668538861478b8&sqlses=e1554bf8b9616b4121dddfe87f9ebe5e&php_version=php8&sql_version=mysql80)

Comment: getting no response, may it be cause i am using different timestamp? not using 2021-11-21 but 21.11 00:00

Comment: What type of `timestamp` column?

Comment: i am generation my own timestamp in PHP and inserting to DB

$timestamp = date("d.m H:i");

Comment: This is bad idea. You should to use MySQL standard 'Y-m-d H:i:s'. Also sure about column type

Comment: can not edit the column type now, error: #1292 - Incorrect datetime value: '12.11 19:27' for column 'timestamp' at row 1

can i somehow re-generate old ones or i have to delete all records from before?

like, somehow replace the old d.m H:i to the standard ones

Comment: You need to create new column - fill it by transform exits data and after delete old column. I think this should be asked as separate question

Comment: yeah, re-created timestamp to that standard format and it is working, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Can we say "I want to have the difference between the max and the min count of last 24 hours" ? Is count always increasing ?

Propal :

```
SELECT MAX(count) - MIN(count) AS up_24h
FROM your_table
WHERE timestamp >= NOW() - INTERVAL (24 * 60) MINUTE
```

Comment: Warning: #1292 Truncated incorrect datetime value: '12.11 20:09'

Comment: @juliaroje86
You should use usual timestamp format like yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss and DATETIME column type, with PHP date('Y-m-d H:i:s')